# Removing a single css property among other css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can remove a single css property among many other css properties for an element in jQuery?

I am currently doing something like this to remove height property completely

```
$('style').css({'height' : ''});
```

the above code is not working ? is there any other way I can remove the height property completely ? rather than setting it to 0 or something !!!

Comment: Why not just set it to zero?

Comment: You cannot remove css rule. There is always a default value, so for height the default is `auto`, so you would need to set it like `$(element).css('height', 'auto')`.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably thinking about it wrong. To unset a specific height declaration in CSS, you use "height: auto;" -- so I think you just want to do `.css({'height': 'auto'});`

Comment: This, in addition to what isherwood noted-- there's a "style" element that you CAN select, but I can't imagine the scenario in which you'd want to do that. It's not the right approach. This is.

Comment: Properties are never really "gone". Set it to what you want rather than trying to remove it.

Comment: @isherwood I was tamering with the css columns. When switching back from the css column to normal vertical layout the width of the css column some how remains, so I was wondering how can I remove height and width completely.

Comment: Understood. This is how. :-)

Comment: @isherwood is it true for css color properties as well ?

Comment: Any. Use 'auto' or 'inherit' or 'none' or '0', depending.

Answer (score 1):

'height':' ' will work if you have already set a height using JS. If you haven't used JS already, you need to over power the css with the styles default option like auto or inherit.

'height':'auto'

Answer (score -1):

this is how it should be specified

```
$('style').css('height' , '');
```

two parameters, not a single object. try that.

Comment: Both will work. You can pass an object even if it only contains one key-value pair.

Comment: missing a . or #?? $('.style') or $('#style')??

Comment: true that. Should have guessed it.